# Do all small-large AdS black hole phase transitions have swallow tail like behaviour for the Free Energy v/s Temperature plot?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes, thermal-radiation, ads-cft

In the literature the swallow tail like behaviour is prominently seen for small-large AdS black hole phase transition for the Free Energy vs Temperature Plot. Recently I was trying to reproduce the results of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.02567.pdf) paper and when I tried to produce the above mentioned plot I got something strange which I don't understand. The plot is shown below:

[image: test]

Why does it show erratic behaviour new critical values?